# Submit form onload won't work

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, form-submit

I need page to auto submit predefined word when page loads and post results.

```
<form id="search_form" action="http://mysite.com/search-results/" target="my-iframe" method="post"> 

<div class="field"><input type="text" value="Atlanta" class="dimmed" placeholder="City" name="City[all_words]" /></div>


  <input class="row_right" onclick="document.getElementById('search_form').submit()">
```

I tried this and didn't work

```
<body onload="submitform()">
```

this one too didn't work :

```
<script>document.getElementById('SearchForm').submit();</script>
```

Comment: `document.forms['searchForm'].submit();` ?

Comment: If you need it to submit on page load you should put your JS code within body onload attribute

Comment: document.forms['searchForm'].submit();  Don't work. The same, the page loads with search field filled with "Atlanta" but its not submitted.

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: <script>document.getElementById('SearchForm').submit();</script> blocks to load page from header down.

Comment: it's because your form needs a name attribute.
<form name='searchForm' action=............>
and then Sebas was correct...document.forms['searchForm'].submit();

Comment: I added the name to the form, then on body tag <body onload="document.forms['searchForm'].submit();">  Still not working http://itmjobs.ro/lidl/src.php

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are calling the form element by the wrong id.

```
document.getElementById('search_form').submit();
```

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/fzTD5/)